# jQuery: Setting 'style' attribute of element with object

Tags: jquery, dictionary, coding-style

I saw this in our codebase the other day:

```
            link.attr('style', map({
                color: '#9a4d9e',
                cursor: 'default'
            }));
```

`map` is defined as:

```
function map(map) {
    var cssValue = [];

    for (var o in map) {
        cssValue.push(o + ':' + map[o] + ';')
    }

    return cssValue.join(';');
}
```

Is `map` necessarily? Is there a shorter way to do this?

It's important to note that the "style" attribute overrides any styles set by a class added/defined in the "class" attribute.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Probably not. A better solution may be to use CSS:

```
link.css({color: '#9a4d9e',
          cursor: 'default'});
```

However, `.attr('style',)` also removes the previous inline style, so it doesn't behave exactly the same.
If you are going to use `attr`, it's input should be a string, not an object, it isn't specialized to work with the `style` attribute. an alternative in that case is:

```
link.attr('style', "color:'#9a4d9e';cursor:'default'");
```

Seems cleaner in this case. In other cases, your `map` makes it easier to insert variables into the CSS.
`map` could have been named better though. It also has an implementation error - it adds double semicolons between attributes: `color:red;;cursor:default;`

A simple solution to remove the previews style is to call `.removeAttr('style')` before calling `css`.

Comment: If you want to clear the style first, go with `link.attr('css','').css( ... );`

Comment: @josh - Thanks, I probably should have mentioned that. That'd be `link.removeAttr('style')` though.

Comment: +1 Though I don't really see the point of the map over using the raw CSS string. It might win you a (very, very) small amount of syntatic checking.

Comment: @CurtainDog - I agree. On another thought, I changed "it depends" to "probably not" - two steps down on my hesitation scale.

Answer (score 0):

.addClass('highlight')  to element. Where your css class is predefined.
 (this worked for me as it didn't want to take 2 style attribute changes)